# "Extracting" the indices tensor from sparse torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

Given a torch tensor A with sparse entries (say, for example, the adjacency matrix of a graph), we can construct a sparse tensor from A by using the function `to_sparse()`.
For example:

```
A_sparse = A.to_sparse()
>>> tensor(indices=tensor([[   0,    0,    0,  ..., 2707, 2707, 2707],
                       [ 633, 1862, 2582,  ...,  598, 1473, 2706]]),
       values=tensor([1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]),
       size=(2708, 2708), nnz=10556, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

But note that:

```
A_sparse.shape
>>> torch.Size([2708, 2708])
```

What I would like is to only obtain the indices tensor in the above "tuple", that is to say a tensor of shape (2,10556).

I have tried `A_sparse[0]`and `A_sparce[indices]` but neither method returns the expected result.

Comment: Try calling: `A_sparse.indices()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [skyzip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8382650/skyzip)'s comment, it is sufficient to call `A_sparse.indices()`